# Json & Powershell query Select

Tags: json, powershell

I have JSON data which I would like to process with Powershell. I can select separate nodes and work with that, but I do not know how can I join several nodes (in case of a goal, I have id_goal which holds ID of a player name from roster (Team1 or Team2). Can some guru take a look and help me?

I am able to pull out as a Out-Gridview a list of goals and with -PassTrough I can work with selected data. But I am missing Player Name (I just pull his ID). How would you join this "tables"?
This is the JSON data:
http://textuploader.com/dmwbf

this is the half working code:

```
$MatchInfo = Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json

$Competition_id = $MatchInfo.competition.id_competition

$Goals=$MatchInfo.goals
$RosterA=$MatchInfo.team1
$RosterB=$MatchInfo.team2

$GoalsTable = @()
$A=0
$B=0
foreach ($record in $Goals)
{
$GoalsRecord = @{}
$GoalsRecord.id_goal=$record.id_goal
$GoalsRecord.id_match=$record.id_match
$GoalsRecord.id_team=$record.id_team
$GoalsRecord.time=$record.time
$GoalsRecord.goal=$record.goal
$GoalsRecord.assist1=$record.assist1
$GoalsRecord.assist2=$record.assist2
$GoalsRecord.situation=$record.situation
$GoalsRecord.pos1=$record.pos1
$GoalsRecord.pos2=$record.pos2
$GoalsRecord.pos3=$record.pos3
$GoalsRecord.pos4=$record.pos4
$GoalsRecord.pos5=$record.pos5
$GoalsRecord.pos6=$record.pos6
$GoalsRecord.neg1=$record.neg1
$GoalsRecord.neg2=$record.neg2
$GoalsRecord.neg3=$record.neg3
$GoalsRecord.neg4=$record.neg4
$GoalsRecord.neg5=$record.neg5
$GoalsRecord.neg6=$record.neg6
if($record.id_team -eq $MatchInfo.team1.id_team){
$A=$A+1
$PlayerName=$MatchInfo.team1.roster | select first_name, last_name |      where {$MatchInfo.team1.roster.id_player -eq $record.goal }
$GoalsRecord.PlayerName = $PlayerName
}

if($record.id_team -eq $MatchInfo.team2.id_team){
$B=$B+1
$PlayerName=$MatchInfo.team1.roster | select first_name, last_name | where {$record.goal -eq $MatchInfo.team1.roster.id_player }
$GoalsRecord.PlayerName = $PlayerName
}

$GoalsRecord.score=$A.ToString()+":"+$B.ToString()

$GoalsTable += ([PSCustomObject]$GoalsRecord)

}

$GoalsTable | Sort score -Descending | Out-GridView -PassThru
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.16299.98

Comment: at first glance this is what is see: you iterate through `$MatchInfo.team2.id_team` and foreach `$record.id_team` (so for each team) you get all associated player names. Thus what you get is an array of  all player names associated with that team id. Do you want the names comma separated? or each Player in a line of its own? It would help alot to understand what you want if give us an example of the data/result you get now and what you expect it to be.

Comment: I want to select data of each goal with its attributes (scorer, and 2 assists). Basically I need the same table as goals are, just instead of IDs I would want to have names.

Comment: This is the printscreen. I have PlayerName now empty. I would want to have its Name there.

https://ibb.co/c5Brbw

Comment: and this is what i get when running your script without any changes: https://ibb.co/jG9DOb

Comment: Sorry. I have JSON data from some other game, (another gameID), but the structure is the same. You get all names in $playername, but I just need the player hiding behind $record.goal. goal holds the ID of a player in Team1 or Team2 roster.

Comment: This is my latest code. I have trouble with the last part, where I am using WHERE. It seems that this WHERE is miss-formed, since it does not give me any output.

http://textuploader.com/dmb7y